# Swipe Animations in iOS

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, quartz-core, uianimation

We need similar kind of functionality in iOS, can anyone help me the easiest path or any sample source codes. I have attached the image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Me also looking for similar kind of requirement.

Comment: This can be implemented based on UIPanGestureRecognizer.  Check below link. I'm not sure wiill that work or not.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894054/recognizing-the-swiping-pattern-for-screen-lock-n-unlock-ios